# Why do copy speeds slow down over time?

Tags: vpn

I am a software developer who moves changes to a customer's environment regularly. To move the solution to their server, I connect via VPN and copy in Windows Explorer from my publish folder to a staging folder on their server. The download speeds start out alright, hundreds of Kb/s, but they diminish over time. Near the end of the transfer, it is moving at only 15 Kb/s and the entire copy takes over 20 minutes.

Today I attempted to copy it over in pieces, one folder at a time. This did not improve my situation. The first piece moved quickly, but subsequent pieces got slower and slower.

What sorts of things can cause this to happen? Does file type play a factor? Any ability to point me in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please consider asking on [su]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SMB (windows file sharing) there are a few network related reasons for a file to go much slower than the actual link speed.  Here is a link to a similar question at Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/4409/windows-networking-performance-smb-cifs that lists a few high level ways to try to improve SMB speed.  On the network side, the TCP algorithm only allows for so many bytes in-flight before an ACK is seen, and this can cause high latency links to have an artificial bandwidth limitation.  Here is an article that gets into more detail about how/why: http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2010/08/the-network-is-slow-by-mike-canney.html.